# GWT Eclipse plugin installation

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, plugins

I've installed Google's Eclipse plugin and GWT Designer in my Eclipse Juno. The installation was completed successfully but unfortunately no GWT Designer options appeared. I can't even deploy my GWT app to .war file.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could it be this: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#multiuser ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think you will have to wait until google releases GWT designer for eclipse 4.2 (Juno). Unless of course you have solved this already, if so then please share :)